# Prisma count many-to-many relation

Tags: javascript, database, prisma

I have an explicit many to many relation that looks like this

```
model Fighter {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  image       String?
  description String?

  battles Battle[]
  votes   Vote[]
}

model Vote {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  Fighter   Fighter @relation(fields: [fighterId], references: [id])
  fighterId Int
  Battle    Battle  @relation(fields: [battleId], references: [id])
  battleId  Int
}

model Battle {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug     String    @unique
  name     String
  fighters Fighter[]
  votes    Vote[]
}
```

A fighter has multiple battles, a battle has multiple fighters, and a vote belongs to a fighter and a battle.
I want to retrieve a battle by slug with the fighters associated and count all votes that belongs to each fighter for this battle. Here is my query to perform that:

```
await prisma.battle.findUnique({
    where: { slug },
    include: {
      fighters: {
        include: {
          _count: {
            select: {
              votes: true,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

But with this query the vote count is not linked to the battle, it means that it will count *all* votes for the fighter and do not take into consideration the battle. I'm new to prisma so I believe there is a way to achieve what I want but I'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

afaik this isn't possible with the `_count` api. This is the best I can come up with:

Method 1:
just include votes and compute the count afterwards

```js
const _battle = await prisma.battle.findUnique({
    where: { slug },
    include: {
        fighters: {
            include: {
                votes: {
                    where: { Battle: { slug } },
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

const battle = {
    ..._battle,
    fighters: _battle?.fighters.map(({ votes, ...rest }) => ({
        ...rest,
        _count: { votes: votes.length },
    })),
};
```

Method 2:
Get the vote counts using groupBy and map it back with the battle query

```js
const [votes, _battle] = await Promise.all([
    prisma.vote.groupBy({
        where: { Battle: { slug } },
        by: ['fighterId'],
        _count: { _all: true },
    }),
    prisma.battle.findUnique({
        where: { slug },
        include: {
            fighters: true,
        },
    }),
]);

const battle = {
    ..._battle,
    fighters: _battle?.fighters.map((fighter) => ({
        ...fighter,
        _count: {
            votes: votes.find(({ fighterId }) => fighterId === fighter.id)?._count
                ._all,
        },
    })),
};
```

Both of these method will produce a response like this:

```json
"battle": {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "A",
    "name": "A",
    "fighters": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "F1",
            "image": null,
            "description": null,
            "_count": {
                "votes": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "F2",
            "image": null,
            "description": null,
            "_count": {
                "votes": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```